# How to find no. of classes with name "myDIV"?

Tags: javascript

/*Please look into this code and please tell how to find no. of classes "myDIV" 
I have tried with getelementbyid also and childNodes.length but nothing is working
*/

```
<div id="example">First div element with class="example"
    <div class="fexample">First div element with class="example"
    <div class="myDIV">
      <p>First p element in div.</p>
      <p>Another p element in div.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="myDIV">
      <p>First p element in div.</p>
      <p>Another p element in div.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="myDIV">
      <p>First p element in div.</p>
      <p>Another p element in div.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
     function myFunction() {
     var a = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV");
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a.length;
    }
    </script>
        </body>
```

Comment: If a `#demo` element exists and `myFunction` is called somewhere, your code is already working.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to build a list of all elements containing the class, use the `.length` property to return the amount.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.myDIV');
console.log(elements.length)
```

```html
<div id="example">First div element with class="example"
    <div class="fexample">First div element with class="example"
    <div class="myDIV">
      <p>First p element in div.</p>
      <p>Another p element in div.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="myDIV">
      <p>First p element in div.</p>
      <p>Another p element in div.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="myDIV">
      <p>First p element in div.</p>
      <p>Another p element in div.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.myDIV');
a.length;
```

Comment: function next(){
        if(arr.length<50){
            elementarray = document.querySelectorAll(' .item-box item-box-active');

            if(elementarray.length===0){
                document.getElementById("btCount").innerHTML="5";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("btCount").innerHTML="2";
            }
            arr.push(elementarray.length);
        }

        console.log(arr);
    } and its not giving appropriate results it is always showing 5